# Why my lists change their value in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie with Python, and I really don't understand why occurs this:

```
vector1 = [1,0,0,1]
left  = vector1
print(str(left))

right = vector1
right[0] = 2

print(str(left))
print(str(right))
```

The output is:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
```

What I really want is:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
```

Why 'left' vector is updated if I fixed it before with the initial 'vector1' value?

I'm sure that this is a newbie question, but I'm used to code in MatLab and I'm getting confused...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `left` and `right` are not copies..

Comment: After `left = vector1`, you have two variables referring to the same list. If you want two lists, you need to copy the list. E.g. `left = list(vector1)`, `right = list(vector1)` .

Comment: Check out the execution of your code in this [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=vector1%20%3D%20%5B1,0,0,1%5D%0Aleft%20%20%3D%20vector1%0Aprint%28str%28left%29%29%0A%0Aright%20%3D%20vector1%5B%3A%5D%0Aright%5B0%5D%20%3D%202%0A%0Aprint%28str%28left%29%29%0Aprint%28str%28right%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false). Then try to edit the code to inspect the change. Use `left = vector1[:]` as @Darth suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say

```
left  = vector1
```

Python does not copy the contents of list but the new list left now refers to vector1

So when you change the new list, the old list is also changed.

Comment: And how can I copy the contents of the list into a new variable?

Comment: `left = vector1[:]` will do

Comment: @VíctorMartínez: see the duplicate.

Comment: To add to this answer, if you want to copy the contents try `left = copy.copy(vector1)`

Comment: This is **not** a shallow copy. It is a **reference**. A shallow copy would be a new list containing the same references as the old list.

Comment: Yes , thanks for correcting :)